# Parse HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I want to create a function using Python to get the website content,
for example get the website organization content.

In the code, organization is University of Tokyo:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <th>Organization:</th>
  <td>University of Tokyo</td>
</tr>
```

how can i directly get the website content without any new installation like get  http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11

Comment: @jesseslu Do you need to download the file? Or only parse and access it?

Comment: Well, you need to get the html file :)

Comment: I think you will have a problem opening this webiste as suggested by others. added an answer to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a `403 Access Forbidden error` using `urllib2.urlopen`  as this website is filtering access by checking if it is being accessed by a recognised user agent. So here's the full thing:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
doc=lh.fromstring(html)
print ''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split())
>>> 
Organization:ZenithDataSystems
```

Comment: hi when i run it , it shows import lxml.html as lh ImportError: No module named lxml.html?

Comment: the lxml.html stand for what?

Comment: Thanks, after install lxml, it still has error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 2, in ?
    import lxml.html as lh
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in ?
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: xmlMemDisplayLast

Comment: yes, i'm using Python 2.4.3. using centos 5.5

Comment: yes, i'm using Python 2.4.3. using centos 5.5

Comment: yes, i'm using Python 2.4.3. using centos 5.5

Comment: Thanks, my company install python 3 in system, but they say can't remove the old version for some reasons, the new python3 in /usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3  so how can i run it?

Comment: Hi, i run it using python3, but it shows [jesse@CLiMB log]$ /usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3 ext.py
  File "ext.py", line 6
    print ''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split())
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: in python 3 print is a function, use print() as print(''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split()))

Comment: Thanks, it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named urllib2

Comment: I have already change urllib2 to urllib but it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 3, in <module>
    req= urllib.Requset("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Requset'

Comment: Thanks, but it also shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 3, in <module>
    req= urllib.Request("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Request'

Answer (score 3):

I like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it makes it easy to access data in HTML strings.
The actual complexity depends on how the HTML is formed. If the HTML uses 'id's and 'class'es, it is easy. If not, you depend on something more static, like "take the first div, the second list item, ...", which is terrible if the contents of the HTML changes a lot.

To download the HTML, i quote the example from the BeautifulSoup docs:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.icc-ccs.org/prc/piracyreport.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for incident in soup('td', width="90%"):
    where, linebreak, what = incident.contents[:3]
    print where.strip()
    print what.strip()
    print
```

Comment: how can i directly get the website content without any new installation like get http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11

Answer (score 2):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

html = """<tr class="odd">
  <th>Organization:</th>
  <td>University of Tokyo</td>
</tr>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
univ = soup.tr.td.getText()
assert univ == u"University of Tokyo"
```

**Edit:**

If you need to read the HTML first, use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/").read()
```

Comment: how can i directly get the website content without any new installation like get http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11

Comment: See my edit for how to read the contents.

Comment: Don't use `urllib2`! Use `requests` instead.

Comment: @egasimus Requests is nice but it's not part of the Python Standard Library.